# VirusTotal API Usage Example?

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to use the VirusTotal API. But it doesn't works
Can you show me an example to how to upload it and get the link of the output scanned file?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take a moment to read this *carefully*: [Ask].  There is nothing in there to indicate we are here to do research for you and then write code for you.

Comment: _But it doesn't works_ [sic] is not a useful error description. Of course, no-one can possibly help you to debug non-existent code anyway. Take the "teacher's" advice, read the link provided and stop being so sarcastic.

Answer (score 0):

There is documentation at https://www.virustotal.com/en/documentation/public-api/

Then at the bottom of the page there are 3rd party scripts in almost every language with lots of examples.